# inode usage is full under / partition

Tags: inode

The inode usage of the server is full

```
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda2        2305632 2305632       0  100% /

tmpfs             490504       6  490498    1% /dev/shm

/dev/vda1         128016      46  127970    1% /boot

/dev/drbd0       5242880  104705 5138175    2% /home

/dev/sr0               0       0       0     - /media/config-2

gvfs-fuse-daemon 2305632 2305632       0  100% /root/.gvfs
```

I checked the directories that have a high number of inodes and found the following

```
 for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
...
/tmp
2206573
...

cd /tmp/
for i in ./*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
...
./orbit-root
2206511
...
```

How Can I reduce the usage of inodes??

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to delete some files, that will undoubtedly free up inodes.

There's no sane reason `/tmp/orbit-root` should contain that many files. You don't say what the files are, or what Linux distribution you're using, however I found https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258459 which states that running `linc-cleanup-sockets` might help here.

Comment: There is no linc-cleanup-sockets command. I deleted some files using rm. The inode usage decreased.